# Upload data directly to brower's indexeddb versus to server

Tags: jquery, html, indexeddb

Is there a way to use the file-upload mechanism to load data from, say a DVD, to the browser's indexedDB such that the browser can then access those files without having to download them from the server?  The web application itself would still be hosted on a remote server.

In this application there is the need for a large number of audio files.  In some cases, the users will not have the bandwidth sufficient to download all of these files.  I'm trying to find a way to get them the files (eg mail a DVD) so they would be able to continue using the application.

I would also like to implement it using this plugin: http://nparashuram.com/jquery-indexeddb/

Answer (score 1):

I think [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) is better in this case. There is polyfill for chrome as well.

Comment: I thought so too initially, but Firefox does not support it!  When looking into why they don't, they essentially said 'We'd rather implement IndexedDB really well, than do both mediocre'

Comment: Yes, I means polyfil for Firefox using IDB. Yeah, IDB is so well that Mozzila thought everything through IDB. But now, I think, reallizing that atomic nature of IDB and sequential access nature of file are fundementally different use case. For example that, there is no way to access middle part of a file in IDB. whole file must load to memory in IDB. Appending to a file is not possible in IDB.